# Capture image response from pandasai as flask api response

Tags: python, pandas, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to leverage pandasai for generating chart based on input provided. And then expose the generated image response using flask API.

```
from pandasai import PandasAI
from pandasai.llm.openai import OpenAI
import pandas as pd
import os
from flask import send_file, request, jsonify
from flask import Flask
import numpy as np #The Python numerical algebra package
import pandas as pd #For working with data frames
import io as io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app = Flask(__name__)

port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 3000))

@app.route('/gdpChart/')
def getChart():
    #Accessing the language model of OpenAI through key
    llm = OpenAI(api_token='<<<<<my_api_token>>>>')
    #Passing the language model to pandasai
    pandas_ai = PandasAI(llm)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "country": ["United States", "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Spain", "Canada", "Australia", "Japan", "China"],
    "gdp": [21400000, 2940000, 2830000, 3870000, 2160000, 1350000, 1780000, 1320000, 516000, 14000000],
    "happiness_index": [7.3, 7.2, 6.5, 7.0, 6.0, 6.3, 7.3, 7.3, 5.9, 5.0]
    })
    # Enter Prompt related to data or Select from Pre-defined for demo purposes.
    prompt = 'Plot the piechart of countries showing for each the gpd, using different colors for each bar'
    response = pandas_ai.run(df1, prompt=prompt,
                          is_conversational_answer=False)

    # bytes_image = io.BytesIO()
    # plt.savefig(bytes_image, format='png')
    # bytes_image.seek(0)
    # return send_file(bytes_image, mimetype='image/jpeg')
    return send_file(response, mimetype='image/jpeg')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Here, pandas_ai.run() pops up an image when the api url http://localhost:3000/gdpChart is invoked. However, I am unable to set this image as a response to the API.

My query is: **How would I set the image response (from pandasai) to flaskapi response so that image would be displayed in the browser as response..**

Regards,
Faddy

Answer (score 0):

You can save any charts generated by PandasAI by setting the `save_charts` parameter to `True` in the `PandasAI` constructor.

```
pandas_ai = PandasAI(llm, save_charts=True, save_charts_path="resources/")
```

I did something similar by literally telling it in the prompt to save the graph. Then I serve that file.

```
prompt = 'Save as plot.png a plot the piechart of countries showing for each the gpd, using different colors for each bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a prompt in such a way that **it returns base64 of graph image** i.e at the end it prints base64 of graph image. And then you directly send the base 64 to the frontend which is returned in the response.

```
resQuery+="''' first clear the previous plt, at last always convert the graph image to base64 value and do not forget to print the Base64 value '''"
res= pandas_ai.run(df, prompt=resQuery)
res=res.decode('utf-8')
return res
```

At the frontend you can easliy decode the base64 with JS.

I did the same and it is working fine for me. And it is also fast comparable to, first saving the chart and then reading via os and further sending it.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to be able to do that is **saving the chart in a particular directory** and then **copying it into the static folder** for flask to fetch and display it. In your backend, you can know when pandasai returned a chart by checking the type of the response. When your query involves generating a chart, response is *None*. You can catch other response types (like text or table) if you like and present them.

This is how I got it to work:

```
# Load in the smart df
def getChart():
    #Accessing the language model of OpenAI through key
    llm = OpenAI(api_token='<<<<<my_api_token>>>>')
    #Passing the language model to pandasai
    pandas_ai = PandasAI(llm, save_charts_path="path/to/saved_chart")
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "country": ["United States", "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Spain", "Canada", "Australia", "Japan", "China"],
    "gdp": [21400000, 2940000, 2830000, 3870000, 2160000, 1350000, 1780000, 1320000, 516000, 14000000],
    "happiness_index": [7.3, 7.2, 6.5, 7.0, 6.0, 6.3, 7.3, 7.3, 5.9, 5.0]
    })
    # Enter Prompt related to data or Select from Pre-defined for demo purposes.
    prompt = 'Plot the piechart of countries showing for each the gpd, using different colors for each bar'
    response = pandas_ai.run(df1, prompt=prompt,
                          is_conversational_answer=False)


    # When your query involves generating a chart, response is None
    # You can catch other response types (like text or table) if you like and present them
    if response is None:
        try:
            shutil.copy(
                "path/to/saved_chart/temp_chart.png", "static/temp_chart.png"
            )
            return render_template(
                "home.html",
                message="Chart displayed!"
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return render_template(
                "home.html",
                message="Something went wrong! Please try again.",
            )
    else:
        return render_template(
                "home.html",
                message="Pandas AI didn't return a chart!"
            )
```

Please note **temp_chart.png** can change in different environments, e.g. inside a docker container. Make sure you're using the correct file name.

If you want to display the image on an html page (e.g., home.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <img src="static/temp_chart.png" alt="Graph" style="width:100%">
  <p>{{message}}</p>

</body>

</html>
```